# how to open url on button click in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a url which i have in NSString urlone which is coming from xml. but i run application it gives excess bad error

```
  // urlone contains  http://www.forasinvest.com/v2/index.php

  NSString*myurl=urlone;
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myurl];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: assuming `urlone` is valid there should be nothing wrong with that. are you sure `urlone` is ok?

Comment: it saying outscope while tracing i have declared that in header class

Comment: NSString*myurl=urlone;
 
 NSLog(urlone);
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myurl];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

Comment: its showing url in tracing through nslog

Answer (score 77):

i think it should work fine, ok just copy paste the following for testing simply

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.forasinvest.com/v2/index.php"]];
```

Comment: i guess you forgot putting @ in the initialization of urlone

Answer (score 15):

```
NSString *pURL = @"xyz.cpm";

if( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pURL]])
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pURL]];
```

Answer (score 12):

The most updated code till date, working with iOS 11.3 and if you're not looking for a deprecated warning, use this single line of code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"https://example.com"] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```